# Django StreamingHttpResponse and mod_wsgi chunked responses

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, chunked-encoding

Testing with django 1.11 and mod_wsgi 3.5, it seems that returning a StreamingHttpResponse will only work with the dev web server, but will always return a fully read response (with content length) when using apache and mod_wsgi.

As I understand wsgi has issues with chunked requests, but shouldn't have issues with chunked responses?

The Python code returns very small chunks with yield statements, that are returned this way in order to avoid network timeouts, since each chunk can be very slow.

Any chance the issue is related to some configuration requiring a minimum chunk size or something?

Google doesn't really show useful topics about chunked respones and mod_wsgi, help is welcomed!

Comment: You shouldn't use mod_wsgi 3.5, it is ancient and unsupported. Either way, if no content length is supplied, mod_wsgi itself wouldn't add one and change it from using chunked response. Only way that could occur is if the ``CONTENT_LENGTH`` filter had been enabled in Apache.

Comment: Sorry Graham, same story as always, not my fault but AWS's for using such an ancient version :(. I have looked at Apache configuration and Didn't find this, any apache's GZIP breaks it? So just to confirm, mod_wsgi should allow for a chunked response without any tuning?

Comment: Not sure about mod_deflate. It is possible that if is a small response under some set size, that it may turn it into a content length based response, which is also compressed. Was the response compressed? Anyway, mod_wsgi shouldn't touch anything, even that old version as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, the response includes content length and is also gzipped. I'm almost sure this was never an issue with file streaming so my only guess is that it's related to the chunks being too small

Comment: Yeah... just confirmed mod_deflate is the issue, ugh.